# is there any possiblity to drag a label to another location in the same parent label in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a label with many child labels, I want it to be draggable so the user can drag it anywhere they want in the parent label space (size x y).
Long search but I did not find any. i found tkinterDnD but when i try pip3 to install thinterDnD for python3 it returns an error of no version of it was found.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: why do you even have a label with child widgets? labels are specifically meant for simply displaying text or image or both, they are not intended as frames nor should you use them like such. Also you could try using `.place()` then

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `place` to place a label inside another label at a specific coordinate. To support dragging an item you just need to bind on a button click and button motion to adjust the coordinate.

Here's one way to do it. This example uses a label as a container, but you can use any widget you want since tkinter allows any widget to be the parent of another widget. That being said, using a `Label` is an odd choice for a container of other widgets. A `Frame` would make more sense.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Draggable():
    def __init__(self, widget, x=0, y=0):
        self.start_x = 0
        self.start_y = 0
        widget.place(x=x, y=y)
        widget.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_start)
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag)

    def drag_start(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

    def drag(self, event):
        delta_x = event.x - self.start_x
        delta_y = event.y - self.start_y

        # move the widget to the new position
        x = event.widget.winfo_x() + delta_x
        y = event.widget.winfo_y() + delta_y
        event.widget.place(x=x, y=y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
container = tk.Label(root, bd=2, relief="raised")
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

l1 = tk.Label(container, text="Label #1")
l2 = tk.Label(container, text="Label #2")

Draggable(l1, x=10, y=10)
Draggable(l2, x=10, y=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer helped